# How to change hyperlink target for dual glossary entries?

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

I'm working on my thesis and was initially using the basic `glossaries` package, and recently switched over to `glossaries-extras` for its more robust handling of multiple glossaries. I have a list of acronyms separate from my main glossary, and many of those acronyms have corresponding definitions in the glossary. The [`glossaries` user manual](https://mirror.mwt.me/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) provides the [dual entry example](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/samples/sample-dual.tex) for this exact situation:

```
\newcommand*{\newdualentry}[5][]{%
  % main entry:
  \newglossaryentry{main-#2}{name={#4},%
  text={#3\glsadd{#2}},%
  description={#5},%
  #1% additional options for main entry
  }%
  % abbreviation:
  \newacronym{#2}{#3\glsadd{main-#2}}{#4}%
}
```

along with the observation:

> For this trivial document, this kind of dual entry is redundant and unnecessarily leads the reader down a trail, first to the list of acronyms and from there the reader then has to go to the main glossary to look up the description.

I'm trying to circumvent this problem by linking directly to the main glossary entry for dual entries instead of linking to the acronym. For instance, in this document:

[image: Screenshot of desired typesetting result in the document body]

I want the links for simultaneous localization and mapping (SLAM) using `\gls{slam}` to target the corresponding glossary entry. The ordinary glossary and acronym linking behavior is fine as-is.

***How can I change the hyperlink target for dual entries?***

So the autonomous mobile robot (AMR) reference `\gls{amr}` should continue to target the list of acronyms:

[image: Screenshot of typeset list of acronyms]

while `\gls{slam}`and `\gls{end-effector}` should target the main glossary:

[image: Screenshot of typeset glossary]

The following MWE was used to create the above screenshots. The `newdualentry` example has been tweaked for my needs:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newcommand*{\newdualentry}[5][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{main.#2}{%
    name={#4 (\glslink{#2}{#3})},%
    text={#3},%
    description={#5},%
    #1%
  }%
  \newacronym{#2}{#3}{#4}%
}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{amr}{AMR}{autonomous mobile robot}

\newdualentry{slam}{SLAM}{simultaneous localization and mapping}{
  Update a map of an uncertain environment (mapping) while simultaneously
  maintaining an estimate of location within that environment (localization).
}

\newglossaryentry{end-effector}{
  name={end-effector},
  description={
    Device specifically designed for attachment to the mechanical-interface to
    enable the robot to perform its task.
  }
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section{Current Effect}

Both of these link to the acronym listing, which I *do not* want: \\
  \hspace*{1cm} First use: \gls{slam}. \\
  \hspace*{1cm} Next use: \gls{slam}.

Acronym-only entires link to the acronym listing, which *is* what I want: \\
  \hspace*{1cm} First use: \gls{amr} \\
  \hspace*{1cm} Next use: \gls{amr}.

Glossary-only entries link to the glossary entry, which as also good: \\
  \hspace*{1cm} \gls{end-effector}


\section{Desired Effect}

I want the \texttt{\textbackslash gls\{slam\}} macro from above to behave as if
I had done: \\
  \hspace*{1cm} First use: \glslink{main.slam}{\glsxtrfull{slam}}. \\
  \hspace*{1cm} Next use: \gls{main.slam}. \\
where these two link to the full glossary entry, similar to \gls{end-effector}.

\printacronyms[title={List of Acronyms}]
\printglossary

\end{document}
```

---

*Clarifications*

A comment by [@cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr) suggested using a prefix on the acronym label instead of the main entry:

```
\newcommand*{\newdualentry}[5][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#2}{%
    name={#4 (\glslink{acr-#2}{#3})},%
    text={#3},%
    description={#5},%
    #1%
  }%
  \newacronym{acr-#2}{#3}{#4}%
}
```

but this forfeits the automatic expansion to the full long-short text on first use. Compare SLAM and AMR when using this approach:

[image: Screenshot showing user cfr's suggestion in use]

This is addressed in [her full answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714373/105905).

Comment: `\newcommand*{\newdualentry}[5][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#2}{%
    name={#4 (\glslink{acr-#2}{#3})},%
    text={#3},%
    description={#5},%
    #1%
  }%
  \newacronym{acr-#2}{#3}{#4}%
}`?

Comment: @cfr Edited the question in response to this.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply modify the macro you're using to define dual entries so that it does what you want. `\gls{<label>}` wants to link to the entry with label `<label>`, so let it. Drop the `main.` prefix and instead prefix the acronym in these cases. That doesn't matter to what you do in the document because the only things linking to the acronyms in the case of dual entries are the glossary entries and we can just add the prefix in the definition of our macro accordingly.

To get the precise output you show, you also need to add a key to make sure you get the right output on first use. But again, that can be done by just modifying your dual-setup macro.

```
\newcommand*{\newdualentry}[5][]{%
```

Drop the `main.` prefix. We want `#2` to link to the glossary entry so that's what we should use here.

```
  \newglossaryentry{#2}{%
```

Obviously, we need a different label for the acronym now, so we have to make our link target the correct place (or we'd have a self-referring entry).

```
    name={#4 (\glslink{acr-#2}{#3})},
```

We also want to get the correct output on first use, which isn't, by default, the same as for an acronym. To avoid the use of `text` on first use, we need to specify `first` (since `text` overrides `name` on first use).

```
    first={#4 (\gls{acr-#2})},
    text={#3},
    description={#5},
    #1,
  }%
```

Finally, we need to make sure the acronym uses the correct label.

```
  \newacronym{acr-#2}{#3}{#4}%
}
```

Job done.

### Complete code

*I only modified the document source for the last part where you deliberately used input you don't want to produce the output you do. Since the input you do want now produces that output, I adjusted accordingly.*

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newcommand*{\newdualentry}[5][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#2}{%
    name={#4 (\glslink{acr-#2}{#3})},
    first={#4 (\gls{acr-#2})},
    text={#3},
    description={#5},
    #1,
  }%
  \newacronym{acr-#2}{#3}{#4}%
}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{amr}{AMR}{autonomous mobile robot}

\newdualentry{slam}{SLAM}{simultaneous localization and mapping}{
  Update a map of an uncertain environment (mapping) while simultaneously
  maintaining an estimate of location within that environment (localization).
}

\newglossaryentry{end-effector}{
  name={end-effector},
  description={
    Device specifically designed for attachment to the mechanical-interface to
    enable the robot to perform its task.
  }
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section{Current Effect}

Both of these link to the acronym listing, which I *do not* want: 

  \hspace*{1cm} First use: \gls{slam}. 

  \hspace*{1cm} Next use: \gls{slam}.

Acronym-only entires link to the acronym listing, which *is* what I want: 

  \hspace*{1cm} First use: \gls{amr} 
  
  \hspace*{1cm} Next use: \gls{amr}.

Glossary-only entries link to the glossary entry, which as also good: 

  \hspace*{1cm} \gls{end-effector}


\section{Desired Effect}

I want the \texttt{\textbackslash gls\{slam\}} macro from above to behave as if
I had done: 

First use:  \glsreset{slam}\gls{slam}.

Next use: \gls{slam}. 

where these two link to the full glossary entry, similar to \gls{end-effector}.

\printacronyms[title={List of Acronyms}]
\printglossary

\end{document}
```

[Please note I can't currently add an image due to an Okular bug. I'm not sure that matters here as an image won't show the linking anyway.]

Comment: Is there any reason to use `acr-` vs `acr.` as a prefix? I haven't been able to pick out a pattern in the glossary manuals of dots vs dashes.

Comment: @drmuelr None. I just know hyphens work because that's my go-to delimiter for glossaries so I feel confident using it in an answer that I'm not likely to be unleashing any nasty surprises on anybody who uses my code. If you prefer dots and they work, stick to them. I also find dots less clear because they're easier to confuse with commas on a small screen. That makes debugging harder. But really, it's just habit. In fact, I almost used a dot because you had. But then I'd have felt an obligation to check the documentation to make sure it was safe.

Answer (score 1):

[cfr's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714373/105905) is great as a simple solution, but it was causing problems with `\glsxtrfull` and related macros throughout my project where I need to override first-use behaviors -- and there are a lot of them.

After looking through *glossaries-extra.sty v1.53: [documented code](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-code.pdf)*, I came up with another solution, again centered on the `\newdualentry` macro. The big idea is to set the [`alias` key](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#glo:opt.gloskey.alias) of the acronym entry:

> This is similar to the [`see`](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#glo:opt.gloskey.see) key but the value can only be a single entry label. In addition to automatically [indexing](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#glo:dual.indexing) the cross-reference, this command will cause the entry with this key to have hyperlinks go to the aliased entry when referenced with commands like [`\gls`](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#glo:gls). Whenever the entry is indexed with commands like [`\gls`](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#glo:gls), the [indexing](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#glo:dual.indexing) will be performed on the target entry (the alias value). See §[5.9](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#sec:xr) for further details.
>
> > Any entry that has a `see`, `seealso` or `alias` key set will be added to the glossary by default when using `makeindex` or `xindy`. If you don’t want this behaviour, use the [`autoseeindex`](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#glo:opt.autoseeindex)=false package option and implement a post-description hook to insert the cross-reference.

which makes this a seamless solution for my project, but with the drawback that linking to entries in the list of acronyms gets nasty. This isn't a problem for me since I don't plan to ever do so beyond the dual glossary entries. The complete macro is:

```
\newcommand*{\newdualentry}[5][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{main.#2}{%
    name={#4 (\glsxtrhyperlink{glo:#2}{{\glsxtrprotectlinks#3}})%
      \glsadd{#2}%
    },%
    text={#3},%
    description={#5},%
    #1%
  }%
  \newacronym{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  \GlsXtrSetField{#2}{alias}{main.#2}%
}
```

Breaking this down...

```
\newcommand*{\newdualentry}[5][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{main.#2}{%
```

I keep the `main.` prefix.

```
    name={#4 (\glsxtrhyperlink{glo:#2}{{\glsxtrprotectlinks#3}})%
      \glsadd{#2}%
    },%
```

the `name` field gets replaced by this monstrosity. `\glslink{#2}{#3}` won't work here because glossaries will replace `#2` with the aliased label, `main.#2`, meaning the main entry would just link to itself.

Instead, I use `\glsxtrhyperlink{<target>}{<text>}`, where the `glo:` prefix in the target is used behind the scenes by glossaries. This is based on `\glsxtrdohyperlink` in §1.3.4 of the documented code, where the alias hyperlink replacement is done. I spent a few hours trying to find a way to use some other glossaries mechanism, but this is the best I could come up with.

Since I'm not using `\glslink`, I use `\glsadd{#2}` to add this location to the acronym index. This replaces the post-description hook mentioned above when using the `autoseeindex=false` package option.

```
    text={#3},%
    description={#5},%
    #1%
  }%
  \newacronym{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  \GlsXtrSetField{#2}{alias}{main.#2}%
}
```

acronyms don't define the `alias` key, but the underlying field still works as described above. Thus, `\GlsXtrSetField` lets me define the field after creating the acronym.

The rest of the code works without modification, and does exactly what I wanted.